# Dash JS Player and MP4Box

Tags: video-streaming

I'm using the dash js player http://dashif.org/reference/players/javascript/0.2.5/index.html but when I insert my dash content created with GPAC I have some errors.

I tried to create the dash content with GPAC-0.5.1-rev4689 but I obtain this error from the player: `MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED` and it stops in the elaboration of initialization segment.

otherwise i tried to use GPAC-0.5.0, the stable version and the player gives the error: `MEDIA_ERR_DECODE` on the first segment and reads correctly the initialization segment.

If I merge the two solutions (initialization segment of gpac 0.5.0 and segments of GPAC-0.5.1-rev4689 ) the dash content works.

the problem should be the initialization segment for GPAC-0.5.1-rev4689 version and media segments for GPAC-0.5.0

Does anyone know how I can fix this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late, but I had the same problem. Here's how I solved it:

The media source extensions are quite particular about the format of the data you throw at them, and there are several things that will trigger `MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED`.

### Mime type

Check that your segments are being delivered with the correct mime type. For GPAC content, it should be `video/mp4`. You can check what the browser (let's assume Chrome) thinks the mime type is using tools->Developer Tools, and clicking on the Network tab.

### Media format

Check what ISO boxes are in your initialization (and media) segments. You can use [mp4parser](http://www.mp4parser.com) to do that. [Here](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-media/raw-file/tip/media-source/isobmff-byte-stream-format.html) is the list of requirements you should check your files against. It also seems that Chrome doesn't like the `uuid` box in the initialization segment. This isn't written in the requirements, but getting rid of that box solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

a bit late, hope it helps.
Google Chrome doesn't like segments having more than one **moof, mdat pairs**. So if your segment looks like the following structure as revealed in **mp4parser**, you will see the error

```
MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED:
stype, sidx, moof, mdat, moof, mdat, moof, mdat ....
```

Empirically, I notice that using the below **mp4box** command, you can generate segments that contain only ONE **moof-mdat pair** per segment, and in so doing making **dash.js** happy:

```
mp4box -dash 4000 -frag 10000 -rap -segment-name segment_ ../../output_12000k.mp4
```

Comment: I used the command `MP4Box -dash 4000 -rap -frag-rap -sample-groups-traf -profile dashavc264:live -bs-switching no -segment-name dash_$RepresentationID$_$Number$ -url-template video-700k.mp4 video-1000k.mp4 video-1500k.mp4 video-2000k.mp4 audio.mp4 -out "dash_unprotected/manifest.mpd"` But when i try to play the manifest.mpd using dash.js, it throws an error `Video Element Error: MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED (CHUNK_DEMUXER_ERROR_APPEND_FAILED: audio object type 0x40 does not match what is specified in the mimetype.)`

Comment: You can view my mpd file [at github](https://gist.github.com/gikarasojo/0c11ad5585f668407902724f9e8d6f58)

Comment: @Leistungsabfall kindly assist [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44818976/3671509)

Answer (score 0):

I have found another answer about DASH.js and MP4Box on this forum and people say it is working. Just follow what this guy says and it will work:
[MP4 to DASH (bash script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742014/mp4-to-dash-bash-script/49740927#49740927)